# How to download response as a JSON file created from Java Object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am writing a code in Spring Boot where i want to download response as a .json file(Json file) which should not be created in any of my project directory but it should be created on the fly from java Object

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadPDFFile()
        throws IOException {


    User user = new User();

    user.setName("Nilendu");
    user.setDesignation("Software Engineer");
    createJsonFile(user);

    ClassPathResource jsonFile = new ClassPathResource("a.json");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(jsonFile.contentLength())
            .contentType(
                    MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(jsonFile.getInputStream()));
}

void createJsonFile(User user) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
    try {

        // Convert object to JSON string and save into a file directly
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/a.json");
        System.out.println(file.exists()+" ++++");
        mapper.writeValue(file, user);
        System.out.println("File Created");
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

I am able to do this with above code but every time i make request it creates a new file a.json in src/main/resource directory Which i don't want . i don't want to create this file in any directoy but still i should be able to download the file

Answer (score 4):

Then don't write  it to a file!

```
byte[] buf = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(user);

return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .contentLength(buf.length)
        .contentType(
                MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
        .body(new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf)));
```

EDIT

To prompt browser for `.json` file type add a header

```
.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"any_name.json\"")
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked. Still i have one issue, downloaded file format is showing File type but data present inside that file is in JSON format. How to make file as .json type file while downloading

Comment: Do you mean you want the "Save as type" dropdown in your browser to say "json"? If so, you can add a `Content-Disposition` header and provide a filename with a .json suffix. Its then up to the browser to default the save-as-type dropdown to `.json`.

Comment: One other thing, you have annotated your method with `application/json` yet you're setting your response to `application/octet-stream`. You might want to make them the same.

Comment: Where to add this header "Content-Disposition" ? I tried adding this in ResponseEntity but it is not available

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to create a file, just convert the object to json using Gson,

```
Gson gson = new Gson ();
String jsonString = gson.toJson (user);
```